# Change position of checkbox label to inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to put together a form with Bootstrap 4 in React, however I can't seem to get my head around how to put text to the right of a checkbox and remain on the same line?

Here's what I'm attempting to get:

[image]

And here's what I'm getting:

[image]

Here's the HTML that I'm generating:

```
<div class="col-12 mt-3 row">
    <div class="float-left primary form-check form-check-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
        <label title="" class="form-check-label">
            I don't want to receive marketing emails. Note that your data may be transferred to a country outside of the EEA as described in our privacy policy.
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the div with class `float-left primary form-check form-check-inline` as a flex and add `align-items-start` class as well as remove `form-check-inline` class.

```html
<div class="col-12 mt-3 row">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-start primary form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
        <label title="" class="form-check-label">
            I don't want to receive marketing emails. Note that your data may be transferred to a country outside of the EEA as described in our privacy policy.
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you try adding `d-flex` class to the div which contains `input` and `label`

Comment: added & nothing has changed unfortunately

Comment: can you also try adding `align-items-start` class to the same div and remove `form-check-inline` class

Comment: Yes! you got it!